# Command line build ipa - no profiles found

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, macos-high-sierra

I've been using command line steps to create my iOS app ipa's for a while now. I've been dreading updating my build system OS to High Sierra as every-time in the past the OS update along with newer xCode would break everything in terms of automating builds through command lines.

Now that I am on High Sierra and using xCode 9.4.1 I can't seem to generate an .ipa based off the archive.

The following command is what I've used to generate the archive:

```
xcodebuild -project Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj -scheme Unity-iPhone -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath ./build/archive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=<TEAM_ID>
```

This would spit out a archive.xcarchive file which I would then perform the following command on:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ./build/archive.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ./iOS_ExportOptions_DEV.plist -exportPath ./build/adhoc -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

Running this command would fail with this error:

```
2018-06-27 11:19:59.789 xcodebuild[27042:735265] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/Unity-iPhone_2018-06-27_11-19-59.788.xcdistributionlogs'.
2018-06-27 11:20:21.364 xcodebuild[27042:735265] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f9582c35d20>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=23 \"There are no accounts registered with Xcode.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There are no accounts registered with Xcode., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add your developer account to Xcode}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 \"No profiles for 'com.MY.BUNDLE' were found\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.MY.BUNDLE' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'com.MY.BUNDLE'.}"
)}
error: exportArchive: There are no accounts registered with Xcode.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=23 "There are no accounts registered with Xcode." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There are no accounts registered with Xcode., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add your developer account to Xcode}

error: exportArchive: No profiles for 'com.MY.BUNDLE' were found

Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=1 "No profiles for 'com.MY.BUNDLE' were found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No profiles for 'com.MY.BUNDLE' were found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'com.MY.BUNDLE'.}

** EXPORT FAILED **
```

Again this command to take the archive and export a ipa worked in Sierra running xCode 9.1. All the provisions are on the machine as well as the required developer certificates. Additionally I am logged in with my developer accounts in xCode. The biggest annoyance to all this is that I am able to manually archive and create ipas that I can submit to itunes connect right in xCode and it all works.

Lastly here is my iOS_ExportOptions_DEV.plist file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>TEAM ID</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If anyone has run into this please let me know how you've resolved it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am logged in on Xcode and I can build and archive from Xcode. If I run the build from the command line I can build and create the .xcarchive but I cannot export to a .ipa file. I get an error "Your account does not have permission to create iOS In House provisioning profiles."

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm useing Mojave with Xcode 10.2.1 and I have the same issue too, and finally I resolved testing different key tags combinations inside the *.plist* file.

After read regarding the *.plist* file tags in the [apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009248-SW1) I generate a *.plist* file with your tags and almost all tags from this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063904/11135813 (only the key tags that I needed).

The problem is in the key *method* value. If you include it, it should be with `<string>development</string>` value (the default value if you don't include these tags). If you include any other allowed value `{app-store, ad-hoc, enterprise, validation}`, you need to be sure that your Apple ID account is allowed to perform the export operation. Check the development Xcode accounts added to your environment, and ask your Certificates Admins Team about the admin role to your account. This role is needed too to validate later your *IPA* file.